Why is JSON automatically being converted to NSDictionary and how can I stop it? Want to convert to MKGeoJSONFeature
So there are a lot of questions on here about how to convert JSON to an NSDictionary, but nothing I've found on how to stop it from happening in the first place.
I'm trying to develop an app. Part of the app, at least for now, is a WebView. In that WebView a GeoJSONFeature, specifically a polygon, is created. I then pass that JSON object to swift via webkit.messageHandlers. So this is in the webview/webpage:
 function sendPath(path){
     window.webkit.messageHandlers.fieldDataPass.postMessage(path);
 }

the path object  here will look something like this:
    {
       "type": "Feature",
       "bbox": [-10.0, -10.0, 10.0, 10.0],
       "geometry": {
           "type": "Polygon",
           "coordinates": [
               [
                   [-10.0, -10.0],
                   [10.0, -10.0],
                   [10.0, 10.0],
                   [-10.0, -10.0]
               ]
           ]
       }
       //...
   }

So as I said, I send that through webkit.messageHandlers. The receive on the swift side is on my WKScriptMessageHandler:
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        
    if message.name == "fieldDataPass" {
        if let messageBody = message.body as? NSDictionary {
            print("fieldDataPass: " + String(describing: message.body))
            showNamePrompt(pathData: messageBody)
        }
     
    }
        
}

Nothing I do here will downcast it to a string, or to anything else. It comes through as an NSDictionary.

I just want to put it in a MKGeoJSONFeature but no type of conversion will make that happen. Why is it auto-converting to a NSDictionary? How can I stop that from happening? OR how can I easily convert from NSDictionary to MKGeoJSONFeature (has to be flexible to handle many different feature types). Please help.

Because you send a path? You can use JSON.Stringify on the JS code to send String, and easily converted into Data. Else, use JSONSerialization in Swift to convert that Dictionary into Data, and String(data:encoding:) to have a String.

To add to Larme's comment: path is a JS object, so when you post it, it doesn't automatically get converted to JSON — it remains in object form, and you get that exact representation from WKScriptMessage. If you do explicitly want JSON, you'll need to convert it to JSON either on the JS side, or on the receiving end, as Larme suggests.
